# Transitive Actions

Tags: group-theory

Given that transitive actions are in a bijection with
conjugacy classes of subgroups of G,
describe isomorphism classes of transitive actions for the following
groups:

$C_4, Z/8, C_2 × C_2, S_3$

Can anyone give me some tips to start out? What does it mean by "conjugacy classes of subgroups"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by conjugacy class?  Generally when people say that they mean a set of elements of $G$ that are all conjugate to each other.  But that's not what's needed here.  What you need to do is describe the conjugacy classes of subgroups.  So basically you have to list all possible subgroups and then show which of those subgroups are conjugate.

Luckily for you the first three groups are abelian.  That means conjugation is the identity so no two subgroups are conjugate, you just have to list them all.  The third group is not abelian so there you will have to list all the subgroups and then some of them *will* be conjugate and you'll have to figure out which in order to group them up into a conjugacy class.

Comment: But even after I've found the conjugacy classes, how do I go about describing the isomorphism classes of transitive actions?

Comment: For every conjugacy class choose one subgroup $H$.  Then $G/H$ with left multiplication is a transitive action that represents that isomorphism class.

Comment: Whether you can just say that or whether you should describe the action of $G$ on $G/H$ in more detail is really up to your professor.  You should ask them how much detail they want.